# Database Selection Failed Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

This is a login page. After login, this message showing "Database Selection FailedAccess denied for user 'rccgbts_shah'@'localhost' to database 'rccgbts_slump'"

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably the user `rccgbts_shah` doesn't have the correcr rights to access that database, just like the error message is saying..

Comment: Double check that all spellings are as is in the users.

Comment: finally fix the problem . In MySQL Databases  the "rccgbts_shah" user name was missing. Thank you Studocwho